# A maximization problem involving random variables: a special case

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, expected-value, quantiles, calculus

Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are jointly normally distributed, 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}
\left[
\begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}0 \\ \mu_Y \end{pmatrix} ,
\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_X^2 & \sigma_{XY} \\ \sigma_{XY} & \sigma_Y^2 \end{pmatrix} 
\right].
$$
I would like to solve the following maximization problem analytically:
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y+\beta X)-\frac{A}{2}\text{Var}(Y+\beta X)-B\mathbb{E}\bigg(-\alpha((Y+\beta X)-r)\mathbb{1}\{(Y+\beta X)<r\}+(1-\alpha)((Y+\beta X)-r)\mathbb{1}\{(Y+\beta X)\geq r\}\bigg)\rightarrow\max_{\beta,r},
$$
where $A$, $B$, $\alpha$ and $r$ are constants, $0<\alpha<1$, and $\mathbb{1}\{\cdot\}$ is an indicator function. The expectation (also variance) is taken w.r.t. the joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

This is a special case of [a more general](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427848/a-maximization-problem-involving-random-variables) problem that I posted before. The blue $\color{blue}0$ in the first formula substitutes a more general $\mu_X$. One immediate implication is that $\mathbb{E}(Y+\beta X)$ collapses to $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ in the objective function. (I have kept $\mathbb{E}(Y+\beta X)$ explicit for comparability with the more general problem.) Since $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ does not depend on either $\beta$ or $r$, the whole $\mathbb{E}(Y+\beta X)$ term drops out of the problem. Hence the actual problem simplifies to
$$
-\frac{A}{2}\text{Var}(Y+\beta X)-B\mathbb{E}\bigg(-\alpha((Y+\beta X)-r)\mathbb{1}\{(Y+\beta X)<r\}+(1-\alpha)((Y+\beta X)-r)\mathbb{1}\{(Y+\beta X)\geq r\}\bigg)\rightarrow\max_{\beta,r}.
$$